# scala macro extract values from Expr

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I have a next code:

```
object TestMacro {

  def test[A](vval: List[A]) = macro testImpl[A]

  def testImpltestImpl[A: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context)(vval: c.Expr[List[A]]) = {
    import c.universe._

    println(vval) // =>  Expr[Nothing](immutable.this.List.apply[Int](1, 2, 3))

    reify{} 
  }
}
```

Example:

```
test(List(1,2,3))
```

How to get real type `List[Int]` from `Expr` and get List instance with `(1,2,3)` values in macro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use method `showRaw` to get `Tree` structure like this:

```
import reflect.runtime.universe._
showRaw{ reify{ List(1, 2, 3) } }
// Expr(Apply(Select(Ident(scala.collection.immutable.List), newTermName("apply")), List(Literal(Constant(1)), Literal(Constant(2)), Literal(Constant(3)))))
```

`reify` returns `Expr`.

Result with indentations:

```
Expr(
  Apply(
    Select(
      Ident(scala.collection.immutable.List),
      newTermName("apply")
    ),
    List(
      Literal(Constant(1)),
      Literal(Constant(2)),
      Literal(Constant(3))
    )
  )
)
```

So you could deconstruct this tree:

```
val vval = reify{ List(1, 2, 3) }
val l =
  vval.tree match {
    case Apply(_, l) => l
  }
// List[reflect.runtime.universe.Tree] = List(1, 2, 3)


val ints =
  l map {
    case Literal(Constant(i: Int)) => i
  }
// List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

Note that it will work only in case when your method `test` is called like `test(List(1, 2, 3))`. It will fail on `val l = List(1, 2, 3); test(l)`. It will fail even on `test(List(1+1))`.

The only useful application for such parameters extraction is macros-based string interpolation [like this](https://github.com/senia-psm/scala-xpath/blob/master/macros/src/main/scala/senia.scala_xpath.macros/package.scala#L19).

Comment: Is it possible in compile time?

Comment: @lito: yes, I've even created a `val vval` like in your code for you to copy `val l =...; val ints = ...` to your method.